# Getting gibberish (%22) when converting BufferedReader to String

Tags: java, post, servlets, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

When performing the following code Im getting the output but some is gibberish. How do I clean up the gibberish?

CODE:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line);
    }}
```

OUTPUT:

```
7B%22eventType%22%3A%22created%22%2C%22transactionId%22%3A%22573975943%22%2C%22transactionDate%22%3A%222019-11-16+18%3A10%3A39%22%2C%22transactionAmount%22%3A%22162.00%22%2C%22commission%22%3A%2212.96
```

Answer (score 3):

What you call *gibberish* is simply an encoded HTML URL, `%s` represents the `"` char for example.

See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for a full list of such encodings.

Or [there](https://www.urldecoder.io/java/) to learn how to use the `java.net.URLDecoder` to automatically *convert* that information into its human readable form.